# Finite extensions of finitely generated free groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, free-groups, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\phi : G \to{\rm Aut}(F_2)$ be a homomorphism.  For example, we have $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/2 \to{\rm Aut}(F_2)$ that switches the generators.  What can I do to see if the semidirect product $F_2 \rtimes_\phi G$ is isomorphic to $F_2 \times G$ or prove that it is not?  More generally, how do I see if for two different $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, the results are isomorphic groups?

Furthermore, I would love to know how to give an example of an extension of $F_2$ with finite quotient $G$ (ideally cyclic) that does not arise form this semidirect product construction.

Comment: You asked three different (but related questions) in one post, which is never a good idea. The second one is a bit open-ended, it is unclear to me if you are asking for an algorithm or something else.

Comment: Please note the misprint (which is harmless in this context), you mean $G \ltimes_\phi F_2$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry about that - for the second question, I was wondering about the (non)existence of an algorithm.  I thought I should put these as one question considering how closely related they all felt to me.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, this question is lacking any context.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am trying to learn a bit about this class of groups and I was wondering what tools people usually use to say things about them.  I feel alright about cyclic groups and free groups, so I wanted to understand how to put them together in this way.  No context beyond that.

Comment: What "f.g." means? Finitely generated? Freely generated?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Finitely generated.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Gamma$ is your example $\mathbb Z_2\rtimes_{\varphi(\bar 1)} F_2$
you are trying to extend $F_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$ which means that you are trying to complete a short exact sequence
$$0\to F_2\to\Gamma\to \mathbb Z_2\to0.$$
It is known that the extensions $\Gamma$ are controlled by the morphisms
$$\mathbb Z_2\to{\rm Out}(F_2)$$
where  ${\rm Out}(F_2)={\rm Aut}(F_2)/{\rm Inn}(F_2)$.
Happily also ${\rm Out}(F_2)=GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

So, it is enough to set $\varphi:\mathbb Z_2\to{\rm Out}(F_2)$
by telling where the generator $\bar 1$ of $\mathbb Z_2$ goes to tell extensions in this settings.

1. If $\varphi(\bar 1)=1\!\!1$ is the $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$'s identity then
   $\Gamma=\mathbb Z_2\rtimes_{\varphi(\bar 1)} F_2=\mathbb Z_2\times F_2$.
   This has only one element, $(\bar 1,1)$, of order two.
2. If $\varphi(\bar 1)=\gamma$ is an order two element in
   $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ then
   $\Gamma=\mathbb Z_2\rtimes_{\gamma} F_2$ has another
   element of order two which is $(\bar 0, 1)$, apart from $(\bar 1,1)$.

Comment: OP is asking about classifying extension groups in general not just when the quotient has order 2. They also are (seemingly!)  interested in classifying extension groups as abstract groups, which is not the same as classifying group extensions. Lastly, how do you know that all extensions split?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I was unaware of the isomorphism ${\rm Out}(F_2)=GL_2(\mathbb Z)$.  But as Moishe said (!), I am interested in the general classification as abstract groups (not extensions).  Also I don't seem to see the second involution, I just see the identity and an involution in each group.  (Also you have the semidirect product going the wrong which I was also guilty of.)

Comment: 1. My intention is to give some contexts by showing a way to think which clearly it doesn't cover the whole picture.  2. The product $\mathbb Z_2\times F_2$ only has $(\bar 1,1)$  as an element of order two since $(\bar 1,1)(\bar 1,1)=(\bar 0,1)$. It has no other because $F_2$ hasn't periodic elements.  3. For the semidirect product $\mathbb Z_2\rtimes_{\gamma}F_2$ could you please describe a non trivial element of order two?